# Php mailer embed image não funciona

Tags: phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar uma imagem no corpo do email com o php mailer
segue o meu cod:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("img/header.jpg", "img1","header.jpg", "base64", "image/jpg");
```

e no html do corpo da msg esta assim

```
<img src='cid:img1'>
```

não chega nada nem no gmail yahoo outlook. alguém pode me auxiliar?

Answer (score -2):

coloque exatamente aonde esta localizado a imagem :

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("CAMINHO DO DIRETORIO 
    COMPLETO/img/header.jpg", 
    "img1","header.jpg", "base64", "image/jpg");
```

Se for utilizar HTML externo também coloque exatamente aonde esta localizado:

```
file_get_contents('CAMINHO DO DIRETORIO COMPLETO/mail_templates/ARQUIVO.html');
```

Se não está chegando nada, talvez seja a configuração do seu SMTP, recomendo  sendgrid.com como SMTP

Comment: cara não deu certo :(*

Comment: Eu fiz deste jeito, sem base 64...                                                        
$dirpath = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/email/phpmailer';                                                                                              
$message = file_get_contents($dirpath . '/mail_templates/email_enviar.html'); 
 $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($dirpath . '/mail_templates/images/logo.gif', 'logo', 'logo.gif');

Comment: voi tentar ,mas por medidas d segurança o servidor tinha que ser interno.